# Instructing method to return only after anonymous event handler finishes

Tags: c#

Inside a static method I am using WebBrowser. I am subscribing to its Navigated event an anonymous method.Can I instruct my method to return only after WebBroswer fires a Navigated event and my anonymous handler finishes?

```
using forms = System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ProxyProvider
{
    public delegate string finished();
    public static class ProxyProvider
    {
        public static string GetProxy()
        {
            string returnValue = "";
            finished meFinished = () =>
            {
                return returnValue;
            };
            forms.WebBrowser browser = new forms.WebBrowser();
            try
            {
                browser.Navigated += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (browser.ReadyState == forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) //waiting for browser finishes loading page
                        return;
                    returnValue = ParseHtml(browser.DocumentText); 
                    meFinished();  //I want this function to return only here. After it finishes parsing
                };
                browser.Navigate("http://example.com/proxy-list/");
                return returnValue;  // don't want to return it here
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                forms.MessageBox.Show("ProxyProvider.GetProxy(): " + e.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you'll have to adjust a few things.

The basic concept here is that your primary method will block until a value is set from the event handler. Since you are on the UI thread at the moment, you will want this to be done asynchronously (so your window remains responsive).

First we need to change the signature of your method:

```
public static Task<string> GetProxy()
```

We will return a Task object here so the caller can await us and get the string return value. Then you need to set up a `TaskCompletionSource` and set it in the handler:

```
TaskCompletionSource<string> navTaskSource= new TaksCompletionSource<string>();
browser.Navigated += (s, e) =>
{
     if (browser.ReadyState == forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Loading)
          return;
     string returnValue = ParseHtml(browser.DocumentText); 
     navTaskSource.TrySetResult(returnValue);
};
```

Now that you have done that, just return the task:

```
browser.Navigate("http://example.com/proxy-list/");
return navTaskSource.Task;
```

Your calling code should `await` *this* method to avoid any UI thread blocking and get the return value.

```
string proxy = await MyClass.GetProxy();
```

Note that the method containing the `await` must be marked `async`.

Comment: There's no need to make the method `async`.  Just return the `Task` of the tcs directly.  Also, naming a TCS `navTask` is misleading.  It's not the task, it's the task's completion source, and should be named accordingly.  Also, rather than having a `TaskCompletionSource<bool>`, his method produces a `string`, so it should be a `TaskCompletionSource<string>` in which the string result is set and passed to the caller.  Finally, it's probably important for this handler to be unsubscribed after its called once.

Comment: Oh, and in your code given that you're awaiting the task before calling `Navigate` (which starts the operation that the task is waiting on) the code will deadlock.  The navigate needs to be first.

Comment: @Servy All excellent points. I have edited to fix (the deadlock one was really good, hadn't even noticed that.