# creation an asynchronous method via event, C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, tap

There is a library which realize IPC via sockets. I must use this library, no other way. This library is a classic event-based library. There are exists events for MessageSent, MessageReceived in client/server classes. So, bad news - these classes have just only SendMessage method, not ReceiveMesage.
So, I need synchronous and asynchronous ReceiveMessage variants.

Comment: What would RecieveMessage do? Just block until MessageRecieved was raised? Why would that be a benefit over just listening to the event?

Comment: ReceiveMessage/Async should get data with/without blocking main thread. For example, I want to realize simpliest RPC analog. Let's server message consists of method name and parameters. Client get message, execute method and return same data back. So, I need to use return ReceiveMessage() or return await ReceiveMessage()

Comment: But an event is already asynchronous. So again, why not just listen to it? The method is invoked when data is available.

Comment: Let's look more widely problem. Let's create dynamic proxy for the same class, which intercept methods calling and realize parallel execution through using different clients. So, Client-server layer is just a transport layer, server and client objects used like internal objects for communication. I need to return same data from interceptor out, but I can't do this till client will send me result back. So, I need to block execution (sync Interceptor variant) or realize async/await (async Interceptor variant).

Comment: Then this is basically a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177538/instructing-method-to-return-only-after-anonymous-event-handler-finishes/ If you agree, I'll go ahead and mark it as such. It still seems like an event would work just as well to me...

Comment: I know this variant, but it's not a good solution for me, because each time I'll use await, I'll create new TaskCompletionSource and subscribe/unsubscribe delegate with SetResult. And big problem - it's not thread-safe if it's not static. One way I though - create thread-safe collection, where I would store TaskCompletionSource objects for each clients. But, I can't reuse TaskCompletionSource without recreation it - there is no way to change state from RanToCompetion in TaskCompletionSource after SetResult call...

Comment: The event subscription should be easy to get around, as for the TaskCompletionSource, if you have two resources competing for reading some sort of socket simultaneously, you have bigger problems my friend.

Comment: Emmmm... So, If I need to subscribe/unsubscribe delegats for event MessageReceivedEvent, this event needs to be realized as concurrency, isn't it? I mean that server can send/receive many messages parallel. So, using example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177538/instructing-method-to-return-only-after-anonymous-event-handler-finishes/ without unsubscribe I'll waste MessageReceivedEvent. So, I need mechanism for unsubscribe delegate I subscribed earlier.

Comment: You should only have one object (and thus one thread) talking to the socket. Otherwise your clients are liable to conflict getting data they weren't expecting anyways. Thus, this shouldn't be a problem. That, and under no protocol I'm aware of can a server send a message in "parallel", be it RS232, TCP, or UDP, everything is serial.

Comment: Yes, I have it one. I know, my English is not so good. 1) I have dynamic proxy for class which intercept any methods call from this call. 2) Interceptor method pack method name and parameters into seriaziable class. 3) dynamic proxy has internal object which represent server for IPC. This server store connected clients and give an ability to subscribe/unsubscribe delegates to 2 main events: MessageSent and MessageReceived. 4) Server class has method MessageSend, but has no MessageReceive method.

Comment: 5) I do not want to create methods in dynamic proxy class for subscribe to these events, I want to use just 2 methods: MessageSend and MessageReceive. It needs for writing MessageSend(sameClient, methodName, parameters); var res = await MessageReceive(); 6)For this I realized simpliest decorator. But my decorator needs implementation for MessageReceive() based on TAP (MessageReceiveAsync, yes). I have EAP server class.

Comment: I feel like we are really just going in circles here. I think if you follow reasonable design guidelines you will do just fine.